# Defining a point on a path by direction of another path

Tags: metapost

Is it possible to define a point when I have two paths such as:

```
beginfig(1);
  u := 1cm;
  path p[];
  p0 := (1u,3u)--(2u,2u);
  p1 := (2u,0)--(3u,2u);
  for i=p0,p1: draw i; endfor;
endfig;
end
```

so that if continuing `p0` to the `p1`, the wanted point would be there.

[image]

I've tried the `dir`* commands, but all the examples I've found seem to either be overly complex for my understanding, or use them in curve definitions.

Comment: Where should the point be? Can you be more precise? Did you see the `direction` operator? Section 9.2 of the Metapost manual.

Comment: @egreg: yes, that was actually *exactly* the part I was referring to with "overly complex for me"; I tried to use the example `z[i]-(x[i+1],0) = whatever*direction t[i] of fun;` as a basis: `z0 = whatever*direction p0 of p1;`, but that gave me `Not implemented: postcontrol(path)of(path).`. The manual says that the first argument should be `numeric`, but I don't know how to extract the direction of the path as a `numeric`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're after?  The `whatever` command represents an arbitrary point along the line that connects the two points given as args so that `z5 = whatever[z1,z2]=whatever[z3,z4];` solves the resulting equations and produces the point where the lines would intersect.

[image]

```
beginfig(1);
  u := 1cm;
  z1=(1u,3u);
  z2=(2u,2u);
  z3=(2u,0);
  z4=(3u,2u);
  draw z1--z2;
  draw z3--z4;
  z5 = whatever[z1,z2]=whatever[z3,z4];
  dotlabel.lrt("z5",z5);
endfig;
end
```

Comment: Yes! This works nicely as well, thank you! I was hoping something to which I could give `path`s, but I think I can work around that.

Comment: Ah, sorry looks like I didn't read the title very well.  I don't know Metapost very well so I'm not sure if there's an analogous construction for paths.

Comment: It looks like using your answer as a `def` works on `path`s just fine: `secondarydef p on q = whatever[point 0 of p,point 1 of p]=whatever[point 0 of q,point 1 of q] enddef;
`, after which `z5 = p0 on p1;` yields the `point`. Nice, thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
beginfig(1);
  u := 1cm;
  path p[];
  p0 := (1u,3u)..(.5u,2u)..(u,u);
  p1 := (2u,0)--(3u,2u);
  for i=p0,p1: draw i; endfor;
  z1-(u,u)=100*direction infinity of p0;
  z2-(u,u)=-100*direction infinity of p0;
  p2 := z1--z2;
  pickup pencircle scaled 4pt;
  drawdot p1 intersectionpoint p2;
endfig;
end
```

`direction` requires a "time"; since `p0` is an open path, the point at time `infinity` is the terminal point. So I compute two points on the tangent line and define the tangent as a path, finding where it intersects the path `p1`.

[image]

Here is your original picture:

```
beginfig(1);
  u := 1cm;
  path p[];
  p0 := (1u,3u)--(2u,2u);
  p1 := (2u,0)--(3u,2u);
  for i=p0,p1: draw i; endfor;
  z1-(2u,2u)=100*direction infinity of p0;
  z2-(2u,2u)=-100*direction infinity of p0;
  p2 := z1--z2;
  pickup pencircle scaled 4pt;
  drawdot p1 intersectionpoint p2;
endfig;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is nice since it works on curves. Could you tell me what is the multiplier `100` for the `direction`?